# How to update/refresh list items of list view in oracle maf?

Tags: oracle, list, listview, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

I have list of tasks. When I delete my one of the task my list still shows that task in the list but on server side i have updated list I am not able to refresh my list. I am getting new task array from server but not able to show it. When I launched my app again then it is showing the updated list. How can I get updated list without killing the app? Both the times I have updated array but not able to show it on the view.

```
    public class ModelClass {
private String message;

private String statusCode;

private Response[] res = null;

protected transient PropertyChangeSupport _propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

public ModelClass() {
    super();

    clickEvent(new ActionEvent());

}

public static String taskId;

public void setTaskId(String taskId) {
    System.out.print(taskId);
    this.taskId = taskId;
}

public String getTaskId() {
    return taskId;
}


public PropertyChangeSupport getPropertyChangeSupport() {
    return _propertyChangeSupport;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    String oldMessage = this.message;
    this.message = message;
    _propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("message", oldMessage, message);
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setStatusCode(String statusCode) {
    String oldStatusCode = this.statusCode;
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    _propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("statusCode", oldStatusCode, statusCode);
}

public String getStatusCode() {
    return statusCode;
}


public void setRes(Response[] res) {
    Response[] oldRes = this.res;
    this.res = res;
    System.out.println(res);
    _propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("res", oldRes, res);
    System.out.println("refreshing here ");

}

public Response[] getRes() {

    return res;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ClassPojo [response = " + res + ", message = " + message + ", statusCode = " + statusCode + "]";
}


public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
    _propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(l);
}

public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
    _propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(l);
}


public class Response {
    private String taskId;

    private String taskType;

    private Integer taskTime;

    private String taskName;

    private PropertyChangeSupport _propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    Response(String taskId, String taskType, String taskName) {
        super();
        this.taskId = taskId;
        this.taskType = taskType;
        this.taskName = taskName;

    }

    public void setTaskId(String taskId) {
        String oldTaskId = this.taskId;
        this.taskId = taskId;
        _propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("taskId", oldTaskId, taskId);
    }

    public String getTaskId() {
        return taskId;
    }

    public void setTaskType(String taskType) {
        String oldTaskType = this.taskType;
        this.taskType = taskType;
        _propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("taskType", oldTaskType, taskType);
    }

    public String getTaskType() {
        return taskType;
    }

    public void setTaskTime(Integer taskTime) {
        Integer oldTaskTime = this.taskTime;
        this.taskTime = taskTime;
        _propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("taskTime", oldTaskTime, taskTime);
    }

    public Integer getTaskTime() {
        return taskTime;
    }

    public void setTaskName(String taskName) {
        String oldTaskName = this.taskName;
        this.taskName = taskName;
        _propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("taskName", oldTaskName, taskName);
    }

    public String getTaskName() {
        return taskName;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassPojo [taskId = " + taskId + ", taskType = " + taskType + ", taskTime = " + taskTime +
               ", taskName = " + taskName + "]";
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
        _propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(l);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
        _propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(l);
    }
}

protected transient ProviderChangeSupport providerChangeSupport = new ProviderChangeSupport(this);

public void addProviderChangeListener(ProviderChangeListener l) {

    providerChangeSupport.addProviderChangeListener(l);

}

public void removeProviderChangeListener(ProviderChangeListener l) {

    providerChangeSupport.removeProviderChangeListener(l);

}


public void clickEvent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {


    try {
        JSONObject paramsMap = new JSONObject();
        paramsMap.put("userId", "1");


        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://ec2-54-226-57-153.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/#########");
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(120000);
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(120000);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            os.write(paramsMap.toString().getBytes());
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            os.close();

            if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    builder.append(line + "\n");
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                }
                is.close();
                if (httpURLConnection != null)
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                System.out.println(builder.toString());
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
                String status = json.optString("statusCode");
                String message = json.optString("message");
                String response = json.optString("response");
                System.out.println(status);
                System.out.println(message);
                //                                       System.out.println(response);
                JSONArray objarr = json.optJSONArray("response");
                Response[] temp_res = new Response[objarr.length()];

                for (int i = 0; i < objarr.length(); i++) {

                    System.out.println(objarr.getJSONObject(i));
                    JSONObject obj = objarr.getJSONObject(i);
                    String task = obj.optString("taskName");
                    taskId = obj.optString("taskId");
                    String taskType = obj.optString("taskType");
                    System.out.println(task);
                    System.out.println(taskId);
                    System.out.println(taskType);
                    temp_res[i] = new Response(taskId, taskType, task);


                }
                setRes(temp_res);


            } else {
                if (httpURLConnection != null)
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                System.out.println("Invalid response from the server");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (httpURLConnection != null)
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        } finally {
            if (httpURLConnection != null)
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }





}
```

Comment: Where's the code? [ask]

Comment: Updated my code.

Comment: @MichaelO'Neill Do have solution of my query?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add  `providerChangeSupport.fireProviderRefresh("res");`
and you have to make public method for  providerChangeSupport.
Here is the link : https://community.oracle.com/message/13203364#13203364

Comment: Done but still not getting refreshed UI.  I have  updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the fix suggested by Rashi Verma, there is one more change required.

The code snippet:

```
res = (Response[]) res_new.toArray(new Response[res_new.size()]); 
setRes(res);
```

needs to be changed to:

```
Response[] temp_res;
temp_res = (Response[]) res_new.toArray(new 
Response[res_new.size()]); 
setRes(temp_res);
```

Currently, because the value of res is changed before invoking setRes, the propertyChangeEvent is not fired inside setRes. Both this propertyChangeEvent and the providerRefresh are needed for the changes you are making to start reflecting on the UI.

Comment: i have updated my code above please check it. I tried what you have suggested but still my ui is not refreshing.

Comment: i am trying this from very long time hope u can help me to refresh UI.

Comment: You are still updating the value of res before you call setRes.
You should not directly access the value 'res' inside the clickEvent function.

Comment: You should not directly update any data item exposed to the UI. Only update them through the setter that you have defined. 

The propertyChangeListener inside the setter only fires an event to the UI if it detects a change between the old value and the new.

This can be seen in the method setRes:
    Response[] oldRes = this.res;
    this.res = res;
    _propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("res", oldRes, res);

In your case, oldRes and res are the same when setRes is called.

Comment: can you please update my above code? There is an option to edit the above code.

Comment: @Pulkit I have edited the code in your question. Could you try it out?